# Is there any syntax difference while defining User defined Function in Mysql 5.5.20

Tags: mysql, user-defined-functions

I am trying to create a udf in mysql 5.5.20 that will return the description from table on basis of code_id. code_id  is primary key of tble.

When I execute this statement, I receive error "Error on line number 5"

```
CREATE function udf_getmateria (id INT) 
returns VARCHAR(255) 
DETERMINISTIC 
begin 
  DECLARE description VARCHAR(255); 

  SELECT description_text
  INTO   description 
  FROM   app_code
  WHERE  code_id = id; 

  RETURN description; 
end
```

Please tell me what I am doing wrong. I am not able to execute this on sqlfiddle as well. One morething I want to know when to use DETERMINISTIC while defining udf.

Please try to create this function at [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2)